# Presentations with flexible page layout

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, presentations

I'm new to presentations with LaTeX; can the Beamer class be used to create flexible page layouts, such as shown below (yellow boxes will be filled with either images or text)? Each page may use a different combination of these yellow boxes, except the leftmost one always stays.

I would appreciate any hint to get started. I have the manuals for beamer and TikZ & PGF.

I am ready to spend some time customizing a template and defining commands if the end product will be reasonably flexible and easy to use.

[image]

Comment: The reason this is not easy is because you have to change your way of presentation :) This is more of a PowerPoint style otherwise you can use the `columns` in combination with `block` environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example using some columns...

[image]

```
\documentclass[9pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{First Slide Title}
  \begin{columns}
    \column{.22\paperwidth}

    \blinditemize

    \column{.72\paperwidth}

    \begin{columns}

      \column{.32\paperwidth}

      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  Etiam
      lobortis facilisis sem.  Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra
      sollicitudin.

      \column{.32\paperwidth}

      \blindenumerate
    \end{columns}

  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Second Slide Title}
  \begin{columns}
    \column{.22\paperwidth}

    \blinditemize

    \column{.72\paperwidth}

    \begin{columns}

      \column{.32\paperwidth}

      \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}

      \column{.32\paperwidth}

      \blindenumerate
    \end{columns}

    \vspace{1cm}

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  Etiam
    lobortis facilisis sem.  Nullam nec mi et neque pharetra
    sollicitudin.

  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Third Slide Title}
  \begin{columns}
    \column{.22\paperwidth}

    \blinditemize

    \column{.72\paperwidth}

    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}

  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```